# How can I cast String to TreeNode in java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Is it possible to convert String to TreeNode in java Swing?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't directly cast a String to TreeNode you create a TreeNode because it has to implement the TreeNode or its extension MutableTreeNode interface.

```
 DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("your string");
```

For further information and examples see the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)